# Initializing fields through attribute?

Tags: c#

I want the value to be initialized according to the attribute When Instance is created.

```cs
class FieldAttr : Attribute
{
    public readonly string key;
    public Key_FieldAttr(string key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }
}

class CtorAttr : Attribute
{
}

static string FromTable(string key)
{
    // will return localized string of key from table.
}

...

class LocalizedMetadata
{
    [FieldAttr("NAME")]
    public string Name { get; }

    [FieldAttr("DESC")]
    public readonly string Description;
    
    [CtorAttr]
    public LocalizedMetadata(string header)
    {
        // I want "Key" attribute to do as below...
        // this.Name = FromTable(header + "NAME");
        // this.Description = FromTable(header + "DESC");
    }
}


        
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foo = new LocalizedMetadata("UNITY_");
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);        // = FromTable("UNITY_NAME");
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Description); // = FromTable("UNITY_DESC");
}
```

I don't know where to attach what kind of Attribute (Field, Construction, Class) will be possible.
I looked up documents about Attribute and Reflection, but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: You need to [reflect against the type of `this` in the constructor, enumerate all its fields and then inspect the attached attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/attributes#how-to-use-attributes-attached-to-a-code-element)

Comment: Since the strings that you want to put in the attributes are hard-coded anyway, why can't you just have the constructor use the same hard-coded strings to initialize the fields?  (Why use attributes and reflection at all?) Is there some other specification for this class you haven't mentioned yet?

Comment: I think we're misunderstanding your question. Are you saying that at run-time you have an object, and you want to get the value of a field that has a `[FieldAttr("NAME")]` attribute? But if you're doing it from within the class's constructor that means you already know which field to use. So it's not clear what the attribute is even for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below solution will solve your problem.

```cs
class LocalizedMetadata
    {
        [FieldAttr("NAME")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [FieldAttr("DESC")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public LocalizedMetadata(string header)
        {
            foreach (var property in typeof(LocalizedMetadata).GetProperties())
            {
                foreach (var attr in property.GetCustomAttributes(false))
                {
                    FieldAttr fieldAttr = (FieldAttr)attr;

                    property.SetValue(this, header + fieldAttr.Key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foo = new LocalizedMetadata("UNITY_");
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Description);
}
```

**Output:**

```
UNITY_NAME
UNITY_DESC
```

Comment: Just a note for others who might use this approach: consider how to handle the case where a developer forgot to attribute a property with `FieldAttr`.  Do you want to initialize the un-attributed property to _something_, or _nothing_?  (Also, what should happen if the field is not of type `string`?)